# SATA 3 theoretical speed

Tags: sata

I can't understand which is the actual theoretical speed of SATA 3.

The SATA 3 interface is known as "SATA 6Gb/s", so the theoretical speed is 600MB/s, but the SATA 3.2 revision allows a solution using PCIe to speed up the interface up to ~2GB/s (16Gb/s).

So, can I say that for products with interfaces related to the 3.2 revision the theoretical SATA 3 speed is 2GB/s?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. **~1969 MB/sec and 6Gb/sec are not even close.**

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - 1969 MB/s and 2GB/s are close enough to be considered the same ... especially when looking at round numbers: your number is less than 5% lower than the OP's :)

Comment: In order to avoid confusion between different SATA
specifications, the SATAIO
has outlined some
basic naming conventions
that are geared to eliminate ambiguity.
Manufacturers should avoid using the terms “SATA II
I” and “SATA 3.0,” as it is unclear
whether “SATA 3.0” refers to the SATA Revision 3.0
specification, SATA 6Gb/s as
defined by the SATA Revision 3.0 specification, or
the SATA 3Gb/s transfer rate. https://www.sata-io.org/sites/default/files/documents/SATA-6-Gbs-The-Path-from-3gbs-to-6gbs.pdf

Comment: As you can see in SATA io web site, up to 2GB/s https://www.sata-io.org/sata-express

Comment: The confusion is because SATA III revision 3.2 allow the use of 2 lane PCIe to reach that speed (2GB/s), so I want to know whether I can consider the speed of SATA III (revision 3.2) 2GB/s.

Comment: Why the donwvote?

Comment: @Wagner As you point out, I think the naming conventions is the root of the your problem. It's not SATA III, or SATA 3. It's SATA Revision 3.0 (aka SATA 6Gb/s). There is no generic term "SATA 3".   So SATA v3.0 is 6Gb/s and SATA 3.2 is 16Gb/s

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, that's exactly the question. Do you have any conclusion about the problem?

Comment: PS: the DV wasn't mine. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, can I say that for products with interfaces related to the 3.2 revision the theoretical SATA 3 speed is 2GB/s?

I think the naming convention is what's throwing you. It was tough just sorting it out in your question when I edited it. ;)

There is no "SATA III", or "SATA 3", they're confusing terms that shouldn't be used.

You could say the maximum for SATA revision 3.0 is 6Gb/s, and that the maximum for SATA revision 3.2 is 16Gb/s.

Or just refer to it as "SATA 6Gb/s" and "SATA 16Gb/s" as suggested by the Serial ATA International Organization [naming guidelines](https://www.sata-io.org/sata-naming-guidelines) (which apparently hasn't been updated to reflect 3.2 yet).

Really, they should have gone to SATA revision 4.0 for this IMO, but hey, I'm not them. :)

Comment: That's it, after reading your comment I found this "Important: Do not use the incorrect terms 'SATA II' or 'SATA III'" https://www.sata-io.org/sata-naming-guidelines

Comment: But my question is still valid, using a PCIe interface to reach the 2GB/s can I say that the maximum theoretical SATA revision 3.2 is 2GB/s?

Comment: Not sure what remains to be answered.  You shouldn't say that "SATA 3" has a maximum of ANYTHING, because "SATA 3" not a real thing, or at best it's too broad of a term, so whatever you say today could be wrong when SATA 3.3 comes along (if it does).  Using SATA 3 just causes confusion, and by continuing to use it, you're just perpetuating the confusion that lead you to ask this in the first place. :)